# knockout console log and observable undefined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've seen comments on console logging observables but it doesn’t seem to work for me. Additionally my app isn't starting up with a the default var that I was expecting.
The two questions are together because I suspect they're related somehow.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/haydenchambers/PctJz/15/).

**HTML**

```
<select data-bind="options: widgets, optionsText: 'name', value: current_widget, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
<input data-bind="value: current_widget() ? current_widget().name : 'nothing'" />
```

**Javascript**

```
var cdta = {};
$(document).ready(function(){

    cdta.widgets_data = [{ "name": "foo", "id": "1"},{ "name": "bar", "id": "2"},{ "name": "bash", "id": "3"},{ "name": "baq","id": "4"}];

    cdta.local = {};
    cdta.local.current_widget = { "name": "foo", "id": "1"};

    alert('current_widget starting value should be: ' + cdta.local.current_widget.name);

    function app() {
        var self = this;

        //widgets
        self.widgets = ko.observableArray(cdta.widgets_data);

        // which widget to display from a local source
        alert('about to asign a current_widget named:' + cdta.local.current_widget.name);
        self.current_widget = ko.observable(cdta.local.current_widget);
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new app());

    alert('after applying bindings name of current widget: ' + current_widget().name);
    //expecting foo
    //but doesn’t alert because current_widget isnt defined
});
```

Comment: @AlfeG thanks that resolved the variable issue

Comment: @Roman Bataev thanks also for the part 2 about the optionsCaption - that’s a real gotcha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of issues in your code.

1. current_widget is a property of app, so you need to do something like this

   ```
   var app = new app();
   ko.applyBindings(app);
   alert('after applying bindings name of current widget: ' + app.current_widget().name);
   ```
2. Since you are using value and optionsCaption bidnings, knockout will set the observable that's bound to value to undefined by default. If you remove optionsCaption binding it will work. If you need optionsCaption and you need to select initial value, you will have to reset it after applying bindings:

   ```
   var app = new app();
   ko.applyBindings(app);
   app.current_widget(cdta.widgets_data[0]); //you have to select an object from the array, not a completely unrelated object cdta.local.current_widget
   alert('after applying bindings name of current widget: ' + app.current_widget().name);
   ```

UPDATE:
I was wrong on #2. You don't have to reset value after applying bindings. The real problem is that you use completely unrelated object (not from the array) for initial value. This will fix the issue:

```
cdta.local.current_widget = cdta.widgets_data[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

But variable/method `current_widget` indeed undefined. `KnockoutJS` doesn't generate gloabal variables.

If You want to access viewModel data outside of viewModel, then You need to store it  somewhere(variable, window, etc).

```js
var cdta = {};
$(document).ready(function(){    
    //...    
    function app() {
       //...
    }
    window.app = new app();
    ko.applyBindings(window.app);

    alert('after applying bindings name of current widget: ' 
      + window.app.current_widget().name);
    //expecting foo
});
```